# Simplest cloud backup options for RStudio projects

Tags: dropbox, r, cloud-storage, rstudio

I'm looking for options for using a cloud service to backup and share projects when using RStudio.

I currently use Dropbox as a cloud service for back-up and file sharing of all my files (including my r code/RStudio projects) across my home and office computers. R version 4.0.3, RStudio version 1.3.1093, on a Windows 10 machines (home and office). I am having constant conflicts due to the .Rproj.user issues discussed [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dropbox-conflicts-with-rproj-user/54059). I would like to continue using RStudio projects, I just need something to back-up my projects that works better.

What do people like and why?

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive often works. Also, you could commission an Rstudio Server, which means you wouldn't have to sync, but rather log in the server wherever you are. If you are looking for backup (in case of an emergency) BackBlaze works (the same as Dropbox or Google Drive, but it takes more work to restore a file and isn't really for syncing across computers).